# Garbage echo after set /a in the macro

Tags: batch-file, command-line, set, echo

i have a problem with my custom macro and haven't idea how to resolve it yet. I hope someone here know the answer and my life will become brighter after his or her useful advise.
The sample ms-dos script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set @test_macro=^
 set /a "test_num1=1"^&set /a "test_num2=1"^&^
 (for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do (set /a "test_num1+=%%n"^&set /a "test_num2*=%%n"))^>nul^&^
 echo ^^^!test_num1^^^! ^^^!test_num2^^^!

set @test_of_test_macro=for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`"cmd /d /q /e:on /v:on /r ^!@test_macro^!"`) do echo %%i

echo Usual call, gives expected output "56" ^& "3628800":
%@test_macro%

echo Call from another macro, gives expected output "56" ^& "3628800", but followed by garbage "11":
%@test_of_test_macro%
```

Gives next output:

```
Usual call, gives expected output "56" & "3628800":
56 3628800
Call from another macro, gives expected output "56" & "3628800", but followed by garbage "11":
1156 3628800
```

This erroneus behaviour changes with number of initialized numeric variables and with order of their initialization, but the script above gives representation of the problem.

Does anyone know the simple and reliable way to suppress these false echoed symbols? It is not always possible to workaround it and it would be very useful to cancel it somehow.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Majority of your code will not run in MS-DOS. DOS has been dead for 20 years.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to define an environment variable which is always of type string by using an __arithmetic expression__. Don't use `set /a "test_num1=1"`, use simply `set "test_num1=1"` without option `/a`. There is absolutely no need to let Windows command processor convert the string `1` (two bytes with the hexadecimal byte values 0x31 and 0x00) into a 32-bit signed integer with value 1 (0x00000001) and convert this integer value back to a string with the two hexadecimal bytes 0x31 and 0x00 and finally add the string `test_num1=1` to list of environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, the question is resolved. It's enough to add ^>NUL after every initalization of numeric variable:

```
set /a "test_num1=1"^&set /a "test_num2=1"^>NUL^&^
```

It solves this problem. Thank you

Comment: `set /a "test_num1=1"^&set /a "test_num2=1"` is not really how you should be doing it. If using `Set /A`, (which is unnecessary because you're not performing any arithmetic), the following would be better, `set /a test_num1=1,test_num2=1`, and this even more succinct, `set /a test_num1=test_num2=1`. The correct way however is without the `/A` option, `set "test_num1=1"^&set "test_num2=1"`. So technically, your issue depicted in the answer above should be solved by using the `Set` command correctly!

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem. In reality your second macro doesn't work at all. It only seems to work, because the variables still contains the correct values, but if you don't start your first macro or reset the variables, you will only see the `11`

Answer (score 0):

Using nested macros is always a bit complex, especially if you try to execute them with `cmd /V:on`.

To handle(escaping) all the expansion phases without even seeing what happens is a bit tricky.

In your case the `echo ^^^!test_num1^^^! ^^^!test_num2^^^!` works fine in your direct invocation of `@test_macro`, but when you tried it with the `@test_of_test_macro` the variables are expanded **before** the rest of the code even starts.
Test it with setting both variables before starting the macro

```
set test_num1=HELLO
set test_num2=WORLD
%@test_of_test_macro%
```

It results in the output of `11HELLO WORLD`!

But using `cmd` to start a macro is a bad idea, because you lose the advantage of macros, they are fast! But starting them with cmd.exe the penalty is much higher than simply calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses, specifically to Mofi: it's better to not use arithmetic assignment at all in this case. I modified sample to use reverse order of calls, it worked for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS enabledelayedexpansion

set @test_macro=^
 set "test_num1=1"^&set "test_num2=1"^&^
 (for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do (set /a "test_num1+=%%n"^&set /a "test_num2*=%%n"))^>nul^&^
 echo ^^^!test_num1^^^! ^^^!test_num2^^^!^&^
 set "test_num1="^&set "test_num2="

set @test_of_test_macro=for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`cmd /d /q /e:on /v:on /r "^!@test_macro^!"`) do echo %%i

echo Call from another macro, gives expected output "56" ^& "3628800" (without any "11"):
%@test_of_test_macro%

echo Usual call, gives expected output "56" ^& "3628800":
%@test_macro%
```